# Planning Scene Validity

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I've been working to get state validity working on a robot other than the pr2.

Sofar I have been able to get make a collision map using Octomap package and also using Ros' collision_map package.  Although I have these working I can't seem to get a successful launch of the environment server.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
<include file="$(find planning_environment)/launch/environment_server.launch">
    <arg name="use_monitor" value="true" />
    <arg name="use_collision_map" value="false" />
</include>
</launch>
```

It seems to be ok if I have the use_collision_map to false, but as soon as I try to using the collision map, setting use_collision_map to true, it returns with the following,

```
[ INFO] [1357342567.800352046, 1481.192000000]: Robot frame is 'world'
[ INFO] [1357342567.802839831, 1481.194000000]: Waiting for robot state ...
[ INFO] [1357342567.802944012, 1481.194000000]: Waiting for joint state ...
[ INFO] [1357342567.834051445, 1481.218000000]: waitForService: Service [/register_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1357342567.975509028, 1481.344000000]: Robot state received!
[ INFO] [1357342567.976648617, 1481.345000000]: Listening to collision_map using message notifier with target frame /world 
[ INFO] [1357342568.889010082, 1482.220000000]: Waiting for environment server planning scene registration service /register_planning_scene
[ INFO] [1357342568.889640275, 1482.221000000]: waitForService: Service [/register_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1357342569.032297694, 1482.347000000]: Waiting for collision map
[ INFO] [1357342569.972849630, 1483.231000000]: Waiting for environment server planning scene registration service /register_planning_scene
[ INFO] [1357342569.973346271, 1483.231000000]: waitForService: Service [/register_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1357342571.050532698, 1484.251000000]: Waiting for environment server planning scene registration service /register_planning_scene
[ INFO] [1357342571.051002291, 1484.251000000]: waitForService: Service [/register_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...
```

I've tried everything I could think of.  The weird thing is that I've tried to implement the same methods used for the pr2, main difference being that the tilt scanner is now a point cloud from an asus.

Is there a specific way to set the service to /register_planning_scene?  I can't seem to find anything to fix this issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51502/planning-scene-validity/) by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 325 on 2013-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank for the help!  I actually was publishing a collision map.  I found that the /register_planning_scene service wasn't being published, I seems to take a while for the collision map publisher "collision_map_occ" to be connected to it seems.  I let it run for about 20 sec or so and it finally was able to detect the /register_planning_scene.

I use Octomap Server like so in my launcher,

```
<!-- fixed map frame (set to 'map' if SLAM or localization running!) -->
<param name="frame_id" type="string" value="/world" />

<!-- maximum range to integrate (speedup!) -->
<param name="max_sensor_range" value="5.0" />

<param name="latch" value="false" />
<!-- data source to integrate (PointCloud2) -->
<remap from="cloud_in" to="/r2/neck/head/range_camera0/depth_registered/points" />
<remap from="collision_map_out" to="collision_map_occ" />
```

maybe it takes a few minutes to start up the publishers in the Octomap Server.

---

Originally posted by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) with karma: 325 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure that you've correctly setup the topic containing the collision map. This includes appropriate name remapping and making sure that the topic is being published. The latter is particularly important: even if there are no obstacles around, you should publish an empty collision map.

See also this [related question](http://answers.ros.org/question/33957/is-it-possible-to-configure-environment-server-with-empty-collision-map/).

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2013-01-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

generally speaking, when you set "use_monitor" to true, the environment server will not start its services until it receive the full robot state. that's why you see "Waiting for environment server planning scene registration service /register_planning_scene" in your output. but i notice that in the output there indeed exists "Robot state received". so you may check which node is responsible for publishing the robot state and check whether or not it's publishing correctly.

---

Originally posted by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) with karma: 741 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2